# Expandable css grid with defined row heights

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to make a grid that has 7 columns and expands with as many rows needed (supplied by backend).
So my css is like so:

```css
.doctor-shedule__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, minmax(auto, 248px));
  grid-auto-rows: 72px repeat(auto-fill,86px);
  gap: 8px;
}
```

what I am trying to achieve is a grid that has a defined smaller first row of 72px and then all other rows should be 86px... but it just doesn't work is there a workaround fot such a case? Using the above snippet makes my third row 73.23px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like below:

```css
.doctor-shedule__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, minmax(auto, 248px));
  grid-template-rows: 72px ; /* first row */
  grid-auto-rows:86px; /* all the other rows */
  gap: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you want a grid looking like this:

```
      +=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+
72px  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
      +=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+
82px  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
      +=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+
82px  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
      +=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+
82px  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |

... auto-fill times
```

So do this:

```css
.doctor-schedule__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, minmax(auto, 248px));
  grid-template-rows: 72px repeat(auto-fill, 86px)
/*     ^^^^^^^^ */
  gap: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my snippet, initially i used "grid-template-rows" but the desired effect would not happen, as I stated the result is the third row being some random number between 72 and 86 px

Comment: hmm... well I didn't try the code I posted and I am somewhat new to grid, but I'm glad the above answer worked!